# Can't use IF NOT with a set in delphi

Tags: delphi, if-statement, set

I have a set of chars which I define in the TYPE section as:

```
TAmpls = set of '1'..'9'';
```

In my function I declare a new variable, in the var section, with type Tampls using:

```
myAmpls : Tampls;
```

I then un-assign everything in myAmpls using:

```
myAMpls := [];
```

I then find an integer (I'll call it n). If this number is not assigned in my set variable, I want to assign it, for this I have tried using:

```
if not chr(n) in myAmpls then include(myAmpls,chr(n));
```

But the compiler throws an error saying:

```
'Operator not applicable to this operand type'
```

If I remove the 'not', the code compiles fine, why is this?

I would have thought that whether or not n was already in myAmpls was boolean, so why can't I use 'not'?

Comment: Operator precedence - you need parentheses around "chr(n) in myAmpls"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi operator precedence is detailed in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence). There you will find a table of the operators listing their precedence. I won't reproduce the table here, no least because it's hard to lay out in markdown!

You will also find this text:

> An operator with higher precedence is evaluated before an operator with lower precedence, while operators of equal precedence associate to the left.

Your expression is:

```
not chr(n) in myAmpls
```

Now, `not` has higher precedence than `in`. Which means that `not` is evaluated first. So the expression is parsed as

```
(not chr(n)) in myAmpls
```

And that is a syntax error because `not` cannot be used with a character operand. You need to apply parens to give the desired meaning to your expression:

```
not (chr(n) in myAmpls)
```

Comment: Would be nice, if the compiler emitted 'Operator "not" not applicable to "Char" type'. Sigh.

Comment: Plus one for taking the trouble to explain (some bot objected that I "might distract the author" by starting a comment with "+1", hey ho).

Comment: @MartynA Thanks. Well, the little green +10 indication at the top of the page is distraction enough eh?!!

Comment: @UliGerhardt Yes, that would be an improvement and surely the compiler knows which operator it has got stuck on